# Query MongoDB geospatial documents with custom maxDistance property

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, nosql

In a MongoDB collection I have some documents with a structure similar to this:

```
{
    _id: "abc",
    name: "bla bla",
    maxDistance: 10,
    location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
    }
}
```

Simplifying these documents are circles having `location` as center and `maxDistance` as radius.

Given a certain position expressed in `x,y` coordinates I need to find all the documents/circles intersecting the `x,y` point.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I tried [`geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear), but this command takes a "constant" `maxDistance` as parameter. Instead I need to evaluate a different radius for every document.
Is this possible?